# neighborhood of diagonal $X$

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\Delta_X=\{(x, x): x\in X\}$. Let $D$ be a  closed neighborhood  of $\Delta_X$ and  $D\neq \Delta_X$, is there an open neighborhood $N$ of $\Delta_X$, $N\neq \Delta_X$, such that $N\subseteq D$?

Comment: What's your definition of closed neighbourhood?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The interior $D^o$ would be open and contain $\Delta_x$, as well as being contained in $D$.

Comment: Thanks. What can say that  if $D$ is open neighborhood? Can I say there is a closed neighborhood $N$ with $N\subseteq D$ and $N\neq \Delta_X$?

Comment: That i don't know.   But i suspect there would be a counterexample.